How to Keep My MacBook Pro Running Non-Stop for VPN Server (No Sleep Even with Power Adapter Reconnects)?
I'm using my MacBook Pro 16-inch (2019) as a VPN server and I need it to stay powered on continuously, without going to sleep, regardless of the situation. Specifically, I want it to remain on whether the lid is open or closed, whether it is plugged in or running on battery, or even during power cycles (e.g., replugging after a power outage).
Here’s my situation:

I don’t mind if the screen goes off since my Mac’s screen is broken.
I access my Mac remotely using TeamViewer, so the screen status isn’t a concern for me.
The main goal is to ensure that my MacBook never goes to sleep so that my VPN server is always available.

I’ve tried several commands, including the following, but they haven’t worked to keep the Mac awake reliably:
sudo pmset -a sleep 0 disksleep 0 displaysleep 0
nohup caffeinate -dims &

Here's my current pmset status:
xxxxx@MacBook-Pro  pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
 SleepDisabled        0
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 lowpowermode         0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         0 (display sleep prevented by caffeinate)
 womp                 1
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by caffeinate, caffeinate)
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            0

The caffeinate command was supposed to prevent the system and disks from sleeping, but I've encountered issues, especially when testing unplugging and reconnecting the power adapter, and sometimes when opening or closing the lid afterwards. This inconsistency is the main problem I'm facing.
I also tried using Amphetamine app, but it doesn't reliably prevent the Mac from sleeping, especially after power adapter disconnects and reconnects. According to Amphetamine, there is a known issue where such actions may cause the session to log out.
Is there any reliable way to configure my MacBook Pro so that it stays on non-stop, no matter if the power adapter is unplugged and replugged, or if the lid is closed or open?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Despite Apple's apparent claim to the contrary in man caffeinate, I don't believe that there is a way to prevent sleep if the power adapter is unplugged.
